# Need to rsync log files from a server that only allows sftp connections

Tags: ssh, sftp, rsync

We have access to our CDN's logfile directory so that we can parse the logs directly.  I want to write a script or similar that will sync the files from there to a local directory. rsync seems the way, except when I send the command, I get:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/compat.c(174) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

When I try to ssh to the remote directory, I get:

```
This service allows sftp connections only.
```

What do I do?

Comment: More or less identical problem on serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/135618/is-it-possible-to-use-rsync-over-sftp-without-an-ssh-shell (in short, the answer is no) btw serverfault is a much more appropriate place to ask this sort of question, SO is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to use rsync to download only the newly added tail of the logs? This is possible with SFTP too. Though rsync is better in that it can verify that the previous content is identical.

For instance, with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), you can do:

```
get -neweronly -resume /path/*.log c:\cdnlogs\
```

The [`-neweronly` switch of the `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#neweronly) ensures, that only new or modified files are downloaded.

The `-resume` ensures that only a tail of existing logs is downloaded (i.e. the transfer is "resumed" as if it was interrupted previously).

To start, see the guide to [automating file transfers from SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*